# What's the difference between test scenario and test case?

Tags: testing

I am little confused about test scenarios and test cases. What are the differences between them?

Let's say I have to test a box of matches. Am I right saying that following can be examples of test scenarios?

- is the box able to contain x matches?
- lets say the box is closed and I shake it vigorously. Are the matches still in the box?

Can you give me examples of test scenarios and test cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example:

You are testing your phone:

Scenario:
    Verify that device automatically connects to Wi-Fi if user creates new profile

```
Test cases:
           case 1: create Wi-Fi profile and verify that it created successfully
           case 2: verify that device succeeded to connect to Wi-Fi
```

In this example you have one test scenario that contains 2 test cases. Because 1st one refers to *precondition*

Comment: So basically test scenerio describes the business situation and contains test cases which are atomic tasks performed to verify the scenerio?

Answer (score 1):

in simple terms test scenarios provides and overview of what needs to be tested in which conditions. Whereas test cases outline how that condition will be tested with positive and negative outcome by changing the pre-conditions and required variables. Therefore, 1 scenario can have 1....1* test case relation.

For example,

Senario 1 - user connects to website using web URL and accesses his profile after successfully logging on as first page.

Test cases 
ability to logon with username only
ability to logon with password only
ability to logon with username and password
ability to logon with incorrect username and password
ability to see user profile after logon 
ability to see users historical orders after logon

I hope this makes a bit more sense. let me know if you do need further examples.

Answer (score 1):

In general, **test case** means *how the test is* and the **test scenario** *what to be tested*.

Here are an example regarding a ATM machine.

#### Test cases

- Insert a ATM card which is valid
- Enter your pin
- Then display should be show with options like "withdraw", "check balance", etc.
- Select the option which is needed
- Finally, the machine should print a paper with details

#### Test scenario

- Insert ATM card
- Enter your pin
- Select an option
- Enter an amount
- Withdraw money

Comment: This answer was completely unformatted. I tried to format it to make it a little bit more readable. Please, fix the errors. You wrote "enter the pin" both in the test cases and the test scenario...

Answer (score 1):

Test cases are something you can depict in elaborated form.

Lets say that the **test scenario** is a "login page".

Given this test scenario, the **test cases** would be likely related to the login page and their attributes:

1. Validate the URL to display the login page
2. Validate the username and password textbox input field on the login page
3. Validate the alert message when username is defined, but password is empty, and the user clicks on login button
4. Validate the alert message when username is not defined, but password is there, and the user clicks on login button

Answer (score 1):

### Test Scenario

> Validate the login page

#### Test cases

1. Enter a valid username and password
2. Reset your password
3. Enter invalid credentials

Answer (score -1):

For an given example: Testing an application like watsapp
Test scenarios: To validate user is able to make video calls.
Test cases: To validate user can make video calls to any number.
To validate the picture quality.
To validate the app doesn't crash when a call is made.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Test Scenario:** A Test scenario is defined as any functionality that can be tested. Basically, it is a one-liner statement which tells us about testing particular functionality. One scenario can have multiple test cases

**Test Case:** A Test case is a set of inputs, execution conditions and expected results developed for a particular objective or output or specific test scenario to verify the requirement.

**Let's take an example of Login and Search functionality to understand the test scenarios and test cases.**

Test scenario 1: Check the Login functionality
Test case 1: Verify behaviour when valid email and password entered
Test case 2: Verify behaviour when invalid email and valid password entered
Test case 3: Verify behaviour when valid email and invalid password entered
Test case 4: Verify response when email and password are blank & press the login button

Test scenario 2: Check the Search functionality
Test case 1: Verify the search field is present and aligned
Test case 2: Verify place holder text was added on search or not
Test case 3: Verify search icon is present on the field
Test case 4: Verify cursor should present on and able to click on the search icon
Test case 5: Verify search field generating the correct result for correct keywords or not by adding a valid search

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A **Test Scenario** is a high-level description of what needs to be tested in the software. **For Example**, in a particular website, a test scenario could be "Check the Login Functionality".

A **Test Case** is a set of actions executed to verify a particular feature or functionality of your software application. It includes test steps, test data, precondition, postcondition, and expected results for testing. **For Example**, **for the test scenario “Check the Login Functionality”, test cases could be:**

Verify system behavior when valid email id and password is entered.
Verify system behavior when invalid email id and valid password is entered.

**In summary, while test scenarios provide a high-level idea of what we need to test, test cases are focused on how to test and what to test.**