# what are the difference between test cases and test scenarios in manual testing

Tags: testing, software-design, software-quality, manual-testing, testcasesource

What are the difference between test cases and test scenarios in manual testing? and also as a fresher I have to know about how to write test cases and test scenarios

Comment: have you tried googling? There are literally thousands of tutorials on testing, which also explain the basic terminology and first steps.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399528/whats-the-difference-between-test-scenario-and-test-case/24573665](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399528/whats-the-difference-between-test-scenario-and-test-case/24573665) Please refer the earlier question on community